# Linux/nix: using pr to format text - how to add line break?

Tags: linux, gnu

I'm using `pr(1)` to play with formatting text files. My problem is that textfiles containing long lines is not automatically line break'ed and contd. on the next line. Think of e.g. trying to prepare a text with `pr` to be printed on an A4-page. I've checked the man page, but I'm confused. Surely there has got to be a way?

An illustrative example:

```
$ pr -n letter 


2021-02-23 08:39                      letter                      Page 1


    1   Hi,
    2   
    3   This is a letter with very a long line. It's made to prove my point. This would not fit e.g. an A4-paper. How do I make ``pr`` automatically insert new lines/prepare the text so that it will be possible to read?
    4   
    5   All the best,
    6   pr
```

What I would be looking for is an output like this:

```
$ pr -n letter 


2021-02-23 08:39                      letter                      Page 1


    1   Hi,
    2   
    3   This is a letter with very a long line. It's made to prove my
    4   point. This would not fit e.g. an A4-paper. How do I make ``pr``
    5   automatically insert new lines/prepare the text so that it will
    6   be possible to read?
    7   
    8   All the best,
    9   pr
```

Appreciate all tips and tricks for `pr` masters out there.

Comment: It's not `pr` but maybe `fold -w [width] letter` will do the trick for you ? You can still pipe its output to `pr`

Comment: Thank you ShellCode. Yes, ``fold`` is an options to preprocess the data. Thanks!